# Can't Start a Stopped VM

Tags: azure

One of our VMs wigged out today and I shut it down. Afterward, I cannot reboot it. I keep getting an error:

Windows Azure is currently performing an operation with x-ms-requestid 7de542381adc1663b6900ded12912df4 on this deployment that requires exclusive access

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Sorry, when I went into the Azure support portal it linked me to stack overflow to ask a question!

Comment: I have seen this error mainly when we try to stop/start several vms under the same time under same cloud service.As cloud service is the wrapper for vms, so behind the scene only one vm can be stopped/started at a time. Its a kind of lock on the cloud service which prevents other activities for the same cloud service.

Comment: Larry, after having had a look and a quick chat with others: No matter what microsoft says on their site, SO is not suitable for *every* azure question, but only for those related to programming, not administration. I recommend migration to Server Fault. I find plenty of parallels to [this case that was discussed on meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281019/reach-out-to-linkedin-about-outsourcing-their-developer-support-to-stack-overflo).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
Get-AzureVM | Stop-AzureVM –Force
Get-AzureVM | Start-AzureVM
```

Maybe the VM is still powered on in background

Comment: I couldn't get it to start up after I shut it down. Eventually after about 30 minutes I was able to start it up, but then found that all the endpoint IPs had changed. Is this expected behavior when you shut a VM down? I had to go out and update DNS to make our web services available again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error mainly when we try to stop/start several vms under the same time under same cloud service.

As cloud service is the wrapper for vms, so behind the scene only one vm can be stopped/started at a time. Its a kind of lock on the cloud service which prevents other activities for the same cloud service. Resolution is - give some time to to the on-going process. Once it finishes go for the other activity.